# many-to-many relationschop in laravel eloquent does not work with pluck()

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, eloquent

I have a many to many relationshhip between 2 tables in laravel.

I just want to get the name of the afdeling with user_id=45.

I tried

```
$afdelingen = User::find(45)->afdelingen->pluck('name');
```

but is does not work. It works without the pluck but then i get a long string:

```
[{"id":3,"afdelingen":"Personeelszaken","user_id":0,"pivot":{"user_id":45,"afdeling_id":3}}]
```

How can i just get

**Model 1 code:**

```
<?php

class Afdeling extends Eloquent {
    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'afdelingen';

    public function users(){


             return $this->belongstoMany('User','afdeling_user','afdeling_id');

    }
}
```

***Model 2 code:***

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
    protected $table = 'users';
    //public function safetyreports(){
                 // return $this->hasMany('Safetyreport');

    //}

    public function afdelingen(){


             return $this->belongstoMany('Afdeling','afdeling_user','user_id');

    }
    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a many to many relationship, `$afdelingen = User::find(45)->afdelingen->pluck('name');` will have a collection of `afdelingen`, not just one.

You can get the first one by using `$afdelingen = User::find(45)->afdelingen()->first()->pluck('name');`

Additionally, you can loop to grab all their names.

```
foreach(User::find(45)->afdelingen as $item) {
    $afdelingen = $item->pluck('name');
}
```

Or if you want an array of the names...

`$afdelingen = User::find(45)->afdelingen()->lists('name');`